# Typescript reduce object array and increment attribute

Tags: arrays, typescript, reduce

Have a item array as below

```
const items = [ { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST" }, { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST" }, { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST" }, { itemId: 456, quantity: 1, description: "TESTNEW" }, ];
```

Need to reduce this collection based on itemId property and increment the quantity based on same itemId.
Expected output is

```
[ { itemId: 123, quantity: 3, description: "TEST" }, { itemId: 456, quantity: 1, description: "TESTNEW" }, ];
```

how can i use Array.reduce in typescript to update the attribute and select only unique itemId
Sharing typescript code used .

```
    [![export interface MiniBagItem {
  name?: string;
  sku?: string;
  quantity?: number;
}
const item1: MiniBagItem = { name: "test", sku: "123", quantity: 1 };
const item2: MiniBagItem = { name: "test", sku: "123", quantity: 1 };
const item3: MiniBagItem = { name: "testNew", sku: "456", quantity: 1 };
const miniBagItems: MiniBagItem\[\] = \[\];
miniBagItems.push(item1, item2, item3);
//start reduce
let seenMap = new Map();
miniBagItems.reduce<MiniBagItem>((acc: MiniBagItem\[\], obj, index) => {
  let seen = seenMap.get(obj.sku);
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
  seen !== undefined
    ? acc\[seen\].quantity++
    : (seenMap.set(obj.sku, index), acc.push(obj));
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, \[\]);

//console.log(newItems);
export {};
```

[image: errors]

Comment: What have you tried? And what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate through each object in the `items` array and use the accumulator (`acc`) to keep a new array of objects with the `quantity` property set.

```js
const items = [ { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST" }, { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST" }, { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST" }, { itemId: 456, quantity: 1, description: "TESTNEW" }, ];

let seenMap = new Map();
const newItems = items.reduce((acc, obj, index) => {
  let seen = seenMap.get(obj.itemId);
  seen !== undefined ? acc[seen].quantity++ : (seenMap.set(obj.itemId, index), acc.push(obj));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newItems);
```

Note: I used a [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here instead of an array for the `seenMap` variable to keep the time complexity `O(N)`.

**The typescript you need to use:**

```
export interface MiniBagItem {
  name?: string;
  sku?: string;
  quantity?: number;
}
const item1: MiniBagItem = { name: "test", sku: "123", quantity: 1 };
const item2: MiniBagItem = { name: "test", sku: "123", quantity: 1 };
const item3: MiniBagItem = { name: "testNew", sku: "456", quantity: 1 };
const miniBagItems: MiniBagItem[] = [];
miniBagItems.push(item1, item2, item3);

//start reduce
let seenMap: Map<string, number> = new Map();
miniBagItems.reduce<MiniBagItem[]>((acc: MiniBagItem[], obj, index) => {
  let seen = seenMap.get(obj.sku);
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
  seen !== undefined
    ? acc[seen].quantity++
    : (seenMap.set(obj.sku, index), acc.push(obj));

  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);

//console.log(newItems);
export {};
```

Comment: i have a type associated to items array . const items : BagItem[]  = [array elements]. When doing acc.push(obj) , i am getting error that "Property push does not exist on type BagItem" . Any suggestions for this ?

Comment: Make sure to explicitly type `acc` as `BagItem[]` like this `const newItems: BagItem[] = items.reduce((acc: BagItem[], obj, index) => {` @PradeepS

Comment: seems accumulator is returning a type of BagItem and when i give BagItem[] , facing a error with argument mismatch

Comment: have edited the question to include typescript file

Comment: @PradeepS I've added the code that you should use, you got the error because you were using `<MiniBagItem>` instead of `<MiniBagItem[]>`.

Comment: Thanks @lejlun . Still quantity increment is throwing Object undefined acc[seen].quantity++ on this

Comment: @PradeepS You might need to type the `Map()` as well, I've made another update to my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236374/discussion-between-pradeep-s-and-lejlun).

Answer (score 0):

Try this filtering by one of the properties of the object:

```js
const items = [
  {
    itemId: 123,
    quantity: 1,
    description: 'TEST'
  },
  {
    itemId: 123,
    quantity: 1,
    description: 'TEST'
  },
  {
    itemId: 123,
    quantity: 1,
    description: 'TEST'
  },
  {
    itemId: 456,
    quantity: 1,
    description: 'TESTNEW'
  }
];

const res = items.filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex((t) => t.itemId === v.itemId) === i);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your objects are not that complex you can work with an easy approach of `deep-equals` by using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`

#### Example

```js
const items = [
  { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST", },
  { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST", },
  { itemId: 123, quantity: 1, description: "TEST", },
  { itemId: 456, quantity: 1, description: "TESTNEW", },
];

const flatItems = items.map(item => JSON.stringify(item));
let reduced = [];

flatItems.forEach((flatItem) => {
  if (!reduced.includes(flatItem)) {
    reduced.push(flatItem);
  }
})

reduced = reduced.map(flatReduced => JSON.parse(flatReduced));

//this code is just for priting the result in HTML
document.querySelector('pre code').textContent = JSON.stringify(reduced, null, 2); hljs.highlightElement(document.querySelector('pre code'))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/ocean.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.2.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

<pre><code class="language-json hljs"></code></pre>
```